# how to use external python library in python lambda function with typescript cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am starting with a cdk project (typescript), I want to understand how can I deploy a lambda function written in python having dependency on external library (request). Also I would like to know recommended practices/ folder structure when working with multiple lambdas in same or different stacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-python-alpha](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-lambda-python-alpha-readme.html) module's `PythonFunction` construct will package your Lambda's dependencies.  The module's docs on [packaging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-lambda-python-alpha-readme.html#packaging) say:

> If `requirements.txt`, `Pipfile` or `poetry.lock` exists at the entry path, the construct will handle installing all required modules in a Lambda compatible Docker container... Python bundles are only recreated and published when a file in a source directory has changed.

Choose a file structure that works for your use case.  The important thing is that the `PythonFunction` construct's `entry` prop must point to your Lambda's code:

```js
new PythonFunction(this, 'MyFunction', {
  entry: '/path/to/my/function', // required
  runtime: Runtime.PYTHON_3_8, // required
  index: 'my_index.py', // optional, defaults to 'index.py'
  handler: 'my_exported_func', // optional, defaults to 'handler'
});
```